# How to get the first item in a List that satisfies a condition in one go in Dart?

Tags: dart

In Dart (Flutter), can I get the first item in the List that satisfies a condition in **one go**?

Currently the way that I get the first item in the list satisfying a condition is as following - i.e. 1) do a "where" 2) then ask for "first":

```
List<Currency> currencies = ...;
Currency dollar = currencies.where((currency) => currency.code == "USD").first;
```

It doesn't accept something like:

```
Currency dollar = currencies.first((currency) => currency.code == "USD");
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you're going to be doing that frequently, you should convert it to a Map, not a List.  Then it's a simple lookup instead of a linear search.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you tried `.firstWhere()`?

```
List<Currency> currencies = ...;
Currency dollar = currencies.firstWhere((currency) => currency.code == "USD");
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this function will throw an exception when no object found.

Comment: you can also use firstWhereOrNull which comes in a package 
import 'package:collection/collection.dart'; Note// you must import this yourself